# Ellipsize works with hint, but not with text

Tags: android

I have a custom edittext and I'm having some problems with the ellipisze.

My edittext is build programmatically and has the following attributes:

```
setSingleline(true);
setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
setCursorVisible(false);
setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
setText(com.telecomIT.digicare.R.string.comment_hint);
```

But the ellipsize isn't working. The weird thing is that if I change setText to setHint, the 3 dots are displayed.

So, why does it work with hint, but not with text?

I already tried to set the inputtype to text, but this doesn't work either.

Comment: you want edittext or textview??

Comment: @RKN op mentions clearly as edittext.

Comment: try using android:editable="false" in your code.

Comment: That would make the field uneditable

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the input type to something other than Null.